# PrimeNG DataTable multiselect filter is fully visible when table size is smaller

Tags: primeng

[image]

PrimeNG DataTable multiselect filter is not showing full dialog when table size is smaller than multiselct filter dialog size.As shown in screenshot it is going below table

I want to always see the multiselect dialog on top irrespective of table/div size and user should be able to select the values

Any suggestions on this issue is much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You need to add

```
appendTo="body"
```

to your multiselect and everything will be fine afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its diaplyaing as expected by adding appendTo="body" to multiselect. But the problem is multiselect popup disappears after selecting the value. My code is <template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
                <p-multiSelect [options]="propName" defaultLabel="All" (onChange)="propsDt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter" appendTo="body" ></p-multiSelect>
            </template>

Answer (score 0):

You can set table's minimum height like this.

```css
.ui-datatable.ui-widget {
  min-height: 350px;
}
```